# Как лучше написать метод "типичный калькулятор"?

Tags: java

```
package com.company.MyFirstProgect;

 class Main {

    double calc (double a,char c, double b){
     char aChar = c;

     switch (aChar){
         case '+': return  a + b ;
         System.out.println();
         case '-': return  a - b ;
         System.out.println();

         case '*': return  a * b ;
         System.out.println();
         case '/' : return a / b ;
         System.out.println();

     }

}
```

}

Я понимаю что он еще должен return тип double, или возможен другой вариант решения?

Comment: Для чего вам несколько строк `System.out.println()` ?

Comment: нормальные калькуляторы делаются с использованием [обратной польской нотации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратная_польская_запись). Тип Double не используется в калькуляторах, так как его точность не достаточна для рассчетов. Посмотрите на гитхабе исходники опытных коллег и получите "другие варианты" решений.

Comment: @pavlofff а как на гитхабе отличить опытного коллегу от любителя поделок? вот беру какого-то человека https://github.com/pH-7 .... вижу у него много звёзд на репах и пр, думаю "о, значит шарит!".....Открываю его калькулятор https://github.com/pH-7/Simple-Java-Calculator .... скачиваю, запускаю, ввожу `0.1+0.2` и наблюдаю эти горячо любимые числа `0.30000000000000004`

Comment: void calc (double a,char c, double b){

           switch (c){
             case '+':
                 System.out.println ( a + b );
                 break;

             case '-':
                 System.out.println(a - b);
                 break;
             case '*':
                 System.out.println(a * b);
                 break;
             case '/' :
                 System.out.println(a / b);
                 break;
         }

    }
Вот данный код возможен  как для решения?

Answer (score 0):

```
Что вы советуете, какая польская запись... Тут человек с простыми вещами хочет разобраться. Всему свое время.
Попробуйте понять для начала этот код.
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expression = "5*5/3";
        double result = parseString(expression);
        System.out.println(expression + " = " + result);        
    }

    private static double parseString(String c) {

        double prewNumb = 0;
        String mathSign = null;

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(c, "*/+-", true);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String nextToken = st.nextToken().trim();
            try {
                double numb = Double.parseDouble(nextToken);
                if (mathSign == null) prewNumb = numb;
                else prewNumb = calc(prewNumb, mathSign, numb);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                mathSign = nextToken;
            }
        }
        return prewNumb;

    }

    private static double calc (double a, String c, double b) {
        double result;
        switch (c) {
            case "+": result=a+b; break;
            case "-": result=a-b; break;
            case "*": result=a*b; break;
            case "/": result=a/b; break;
            default: result=a;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Скажем так, с токенайзером я не знаком еще. но в принципе понятно